# Javascript functions in separate file or along with html when loading by ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

We have started doing more dynamic content loading by ajax, and a pattern that has evolved is to include functions along with the html that we load and paste into divs. So if the main html page has a div:

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

we load stuff like this into that div:

```
<div id="b" onchange="dostuff();">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dostuff() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

The dostuff method here will generally not contain any server-generated stuff (by php or jsp), it's more a convenience thing, having the javascript code in the vicinity of the html it operates on makes it easier to find the functions and/or look at all related code in one file.

In another project I worked in we tended to put functions like dostuff() in a separate .js file (usually one .js file would contain many functions that were used across several dynamically loaded html chunks), which was loaded once when the main page loaded. This feels like a better solution to me, but when I want to argue that point in the team it's hard for me to pinpoint pros and cons - maybe I'm wrong?

One thing I've noticed is that it's harder to debug in Firebug, as the function I put a breakpoint in has reloaded, which confuses the debugger. Also maybe performance degrades as the browser recompiles functions?

Comment: I always use live bindings ( .live() ) where possible, so elements that are loaded via ajax calls have their's events ready for them. You can also use .on() and .off() if you want to control page load.

Comment: If it is possible, you can reference your external script with `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say don't mix markup and logic. Put all JavaScript in a separate file and assign events there as well, that way it'll be less confusing and more portable.

html:

```
<div id="b">...</div>
```

js:

```
var b = document.querySelector('#b');
b.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // do something
});
```

This will work assuming `b` is static, otherwise look into "event delegation".

> Also maybe performance degrades as the browser recompiles functions?

To get the best performance, is better to have your JavaScript in separate files, that way you can just concat and minify everything and load only one file in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

one thing is if you include it with your html that the way you do it, dostuff is a global function (which in general is a bad idea). at least use 1 global namespace variable-object literal, and append everything to that variable:

```
var YOURNAMESPACE = {};
```

and in your include:

```
<div id="b">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  YOURNAMESPACE.dostuff = function () {
    // ...
  };

  document.getElementById('b').onchange = function () {
    YOURNAMESPACE.dostuff();
  }
</script>
```

as you see i dont use a javascript attribute in my code. it is just bad practice to that!

regarding your question, it depends. there are arguments for loading it with your ajax request, because of the initial page-load-time.

an argument which speaks for doing it within 1 file is, that it is obviously easier to structure your javascript and have an better overview. you can (and should) minify/uglify your javascript file!

you generally should think about your ajax pattern. are you able to to ajax with json? your ajax request should be a lot faster with. (if you do it with json, your question is obsolete, because you cant send javascript code to the browser via json).

Comment: I tried this in Firebug: var YOURNAMESPACE = {}; function YOURNAMESPACE.dostuff() {};
but got the error "SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters" - was it supposed to be pseudo-code?

Comment: my fault im sorry, to fast typing, i fixed it.

Comment: Cool, that structure I recognise.